# C++ simple files compilation using "gcc" compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, static-linking

I'm trying to compile a very simple c++ code and get a linking error depending on sequence of gcc parameters. Could anybody explains what is the difference between these two command line rows?

// This works fine

```
gcc -x c++ -c *.h *.cpp (first I pass *.h files then *.cpp)
gcc -lstdc++ *.o -o exe
```

// This gives an error

```
gcc -x c++ -c *.cpp *.h (first I pass *.cpp files then *.h) 
gcc -lstdc++ *.o -o exe
```

Does gcc care of the parameters sequence?

Examples:

// THIS CASE WORKS FINE

```
    [karen@linux40 ~/C++]$ ls
    Employee.cpp  Employee.h  Main.cpp
    [karen@linux40 ~/C++]$ gcc -x c++ -c *.h *.cpp
    [karen@linux40 ~/C++]$ ls
    Employee.cpp  Employee.h  Employee.o  Main.cpp  Main.o  Makefile
    [karen@linux40 ~/C++]$ gcc -lstdc++ *.o -o exe
    [karen@linux40 ~/C++]$ ls
    exe  Employee.cpp  Employee.h  Employee.o  Main.cpp  Main.o
```

// THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC CASE

```
    [karen@linux40 ~/C++]$ ls
    Employee.cpp  Employee.h  Main.cpp
    [karen@linux40 ~/C++]$ gcc -x c++ -c *.cpp *.h
    [karen@linux40 ~/C++]$ ls
    Employee.cpp  Employee.h  Employee.o  Main.cpp  Main.o
    [karen@linux40 ~/C++]$ gcc -lstdc++ *.o -o exe
    Main.o: In function `main':
    Main.cpp:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `Employee::Employee()'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Employee.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Employee {
public:
    Employee();
    Employee(string theName, float thePayRate);

    string getName() const;
    float getPayRate() const;

    float pay(float hoursWorked) const;

protected:
    string name;
    float payRate;
};
```

Employee.cpp

```
#include "Employee.h"

Employee::Employee() {
}

Employee::Employee(string theName, float thePayRate) {
    name = theName;
    payRate = thePayRate;
}

string Employee::getName() const {
    return name;
}

float Employee::getPayRate() const {
    return payRate;
}

float Employee::pay(float hoursWorked) const {
    return hoursWorked * payRate;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Employee.h"

int main() {
    Employee e;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not pass .h files to gcc.

Comment: What's the 'error'?  Also, what's in your `*.h` files that they have to be fed to the compiler explicitly?

Comment: And yes it does care about the order of the linked libraries, even though this is not related to your error exactly, but sort of related to your question

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I don't need to pass ".h" files.
But why gcc feels find when we pass at first ".h" then ".cpp" files, and complains in vice versa?

To see the error message, please look at my updated data.
Thanks,
Karen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you should not pass .h file directly to compiler. That does not make any sense and is not correct.

But looks like the question here is mainly for understanding how gcc works. So my answer is from this perspective.

I assume you include the same .h file in .cpp file.

What happens when you pass the .cpp first then .h, the compiler sees a declaration, then definition and then again a declaration. This causes a linker error, as there is no corresponding definition for the second declaration.

In contrast if you pass the .h first then .cpp, it sees two declarations and then the definition, which links fine.

Comment: @CollinHockey that's a lame comment, too bad we cannot downvote comments. I think grigy was being polite...(+1) to correct this.

Comment: Quite logical explanation ... 

Thank you,
Karen

Answer (score 1):

I presume that the questioner is using headers in a non-standard location, hence passing them explicitly to the compiler. If the code in *.c needs *.h to work, then passing the headers in after the code will give an error where the opposite order doesn't.

If you're including the headers with

```
#include <file.h>
```

the compiler won't find them in the current directory (unless you keep your code in /usr/include...), so use

```
#include "file.h"
```

instead for headers located in the same directory as the code. If they're somewhere else, add

```
-I /path/to/headers/
```

to the gcc command.

Good luck!

Comment: Please see my attached code. Actually I used "" and not <>

Thanks
Karen

Comment: So, are you headers in the same directory as your code? If so, leaving off the '*.h' entirely should work correctly.

Comment: Yes, exactly! They are in a same directory. I've updated the problem description and there you can see the result of the shell command "ls" which shows that I have three files in the same directory.

Thanks for being interested and trying to help me.

Comment: I've compiled your code and I get the same error as you if I put '*.h' on the end of the command. A previous answerer has explained why it fails, but to get it to work you just need to omit '*.h' entirely: 'gcc -x c++ -c *.cpp'.